# Bootstrapvalidator - exclude field from validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

How can I exclude particular form fields from being validated?

I have tried to use the 'group' setting to differentiate fields that do not require validation:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_1">
</div>
<div class="group">
<div class="col-md-4" group>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_2" data-bv-group=".group">
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#form').bootstrapValidator({
message: 'This value is not valid',
excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden', ':not(:visible)', '.group'],
group: '.form-group', // Set for all fields
fields: {
    name_1: {
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: required_line_text
            }
        }
    },
    name_2: {
        field: '.group',
        excluded: true
    }
}
```

On form submission, the name_2 field is showing red. I would like it to show green even with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_1">
</div>
<div class="group">
<div class="col-md-4" group>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_2" data-bv-excluded="false">
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#form').bootstrapValidator({
message: 'This value is not valid',
excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden', ':not(:visible)'],
fields: {
    name_1: {
        validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: required_line_text
            }
        }
    },
    name_2: {
        excluded: 'false',
        validators: {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```